# change data type in dataframe if its contain more object then it will be object else it will be a number format type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to ask how can I make dataframe when reading data to check if most of column is number type so that it makes it as int or float. if its not number related it will be come as an object. For example the below image we have 4 columns and when i import it as dataframe all of them will be in a form of an object format. My goal is to make col1,col2 and col3 as int or float since most of the data is number and "error or missing or any other letter" will be (nan or 0) and col4 to be as an object since most of the data is not a number. The below example is only one concept of dataset so i need a way that can be dynamic for all dataset

Thank you

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBv2L.png)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas functions for reading data (such as `read_csv`, `read_excel`) have a `dtype` argument, where you can specify – per column – what the data type should be.

You can either force it to read certain columns as ints/floats (`dtype={'col1': int}`), or read it as `object` (e.g. `dtype={'col1': object}`) and only later convert it to a specific data type based on the column content.

See more [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I cant specify the col name and its data type because it need to be dynamic. when I use pandas to import data all of them will be object since they have string in them so i need way after i import data to fix data based on data that inside it